# Construct Binary Search Tree from PreOrder

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, preorder

Way to construct binary search tree from preorderTransaversal.Please suggest if there is any suggestion.

```
Node constructTreeFromPreorder(int[] arr,int start,int end)
{
if(arr==null){
    return null;
}else{
    if(start>end){
        return null;
    }
    int element=arr[start];
    Node node=new Node(element); // create node
    if(start==end){
        return node;
    }
    int index=start+1;
    for(int i=index;i<=end;i++){
          index=i;
        if(arr[i]>element){
            break;
        }
    }
    node.left=constructTreeFromPreorder(arr, start+1, index-1);
    node.right=constructTreeFromPreorder(arr, index, end);
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple binary trees that correspond to any preorder traversal. For example, consider the preorder traversal `[2,1,3]`. That is the preorder traversal for all of these trees:

```
  2         2     2          2      2
1   3     1         1      1          1
        3         3          3          3
```

You need more information than just a preorder traversal if you want to uniquely describe a binary tree.

**Added after you modified the question:** Of those, only the first is a valid binary search tree. I'm not sure if there are multiple BSTs for a given preorder traversal.

If there are duplicate items in the list, then there can be multiple trees for any given preorder traversal.

Comment: But for Binary search tree combination will be differ and less.